# Android Java - switch issue

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I'm working on a test application which requires connection to server and save the response from it. The response actually is a data packet,so I need to understand what type of packet it is and to execute it.For now I can receive the response, calculate the  data packet and now I need a little help with switch method where I want to get the packet type.

Here is the code I'm using :

```
                    RPCPacket packet=null;
                    switch(RPCPacketType.getPacketTypeByValue(pType)){
                        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_INFO_START:
                        {
                            packet = new InfoStartRPCPacket(    objectIdentificator,
                                                                RPCPacketType.getPacketTypeByValue(pType),
                                                                RPCOperationType.getByValue(Integer.parseInt(operation)),
                                                                objectId,
                                                                id,
                                                                Integer.parseInt(size),
                                                                hash,
                                                                RPCPacketDataType.getByValue(dataType),
                                                                first );
                            break;
                        }
                        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_INFO_END:{
                            packet = new InfoEndRPCPacket();

                            break;
                        }
                        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_INFO_ERROR:{
                            packet = new InfoErrorRPCPacket();

                            break;
                        }
                            // Basic packets
                        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_COLLECTION:{
                            packet = new CollectionRPCPacket();

                            break;
                        }
                        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_CATEGORY:{
                            packet = new CategoryRPCPacket();

                            break;
                        }
                        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_CARD:{
                            packet = new CardRPCPacket();

                            break;
                        }
                        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_MESSAGE:{
                            packet = new MessageRPCPacket();

                            break;
                        }
                        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_GENRE:{
                            packet = new GenreRPCPacket();

                            break;
                        }
                        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_TAG:{
                            packet = new TagRPCPacket();

                            break;
                        }
                        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_USER:{
                            packet = new UserRPCPacket();

                            break;
                        }
                        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_CARDSTATS_CATEGORY:{
                            packet = new CardStatsCategoryRPCPacket();

                            break;
                        }
                        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_CONTENT:{
                            packet = new ContentRPCPacket();

                            break;
                        }
                            // Media packets
                        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_MEDIA_COLLECTION:{
                            packet = new MediaCollectionRPCPacket();

                            break;
                        }
                        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_MEDIA_CATEGORY:{
                            packet = new MediaCategoryRPCPacket();

                            break;
                        }
                        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_MEDIA_CARD:{
                            packet = new MediaCardRPCPacket();

                            break;
                        }
                        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_MEDIA_TAG:{
                            packet = new MediaTagRPCPacket();

                            break;
                        }
                        case ST_OBJECT_TYPE_MEDIA_COLLECTION_BUTTON:{
                            packet = new MediaCollectionButtonRPCPacket();

                            break;
                        }
                            // unknown packet
                        default: {
                            packet=null;

                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

I need a way to be able to initialize the packet as InfoStartRPCPacket or something different after I check the all switches.Basically I want to be able to do something like this outside switch :

```
packet.executeInfoStartPacket(/*params*/);  , when executeInfoStartPacket is a method in InfoStartRPCPacket class.
```

Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Haven't you already implemented the switch statement?

Comment: Yes.I mean, when I run the switch statement and packetType is for example InfoStart I want to be able to set the global packet to InfoStart and execute it as calling executeInfoStart() method from it's own class. Did you understand it?

Comment: Please don't post tons of code when only a small part of it is relevant to your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do that and you shouldn't.

Instead you could have an `abstract` method in your `RPCPacket` class called `process()` (possibly giving any necessary context as parameters) and overload that in each specific sub-class.

This way the packet-specific code automatically has access to all the packet-specific fields and methods.

Comment: Actually If I create an Interface and all of my child classes extends RPCPacket and implements Interface,is this will be a solution.And create method process() in Interface?Will this solve my problem?

Comment: @Android-Droid: this won't help *unless* `RPCPacket` implements this interface as well *or* you cast to that interface (hoping that all `RPCPacket` implementations *really* implement it). But why should you? What's wrong with adding that method to that class? I see no advantage in adding another interface.